# value of array changes when it exits the loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Thank you! fread(&byte[i], sizeof(BYTE), 1, inptr) solve the problem.

Part of the code:

```
BYTE (byte[block_size]);
for (int i = 0; i < block_size; i++)
    {
        fread(&byte, sizeof(BYTE), 1, inptr);
        byte[i] = *byte;
        printf("b[%i] = %i\t", i, byte[i]);
    }
    printf("b0 = %i, b1 = %i, b2 = %i, b3 = %i\n", byte[0], byte[1], byte[2], byte[3]);
    return 0;
```

Inside "for loop" byte's values are printed correctly. byte[0] has value 104.
Outside of the loop value for byte[0] is 0.
Why it is not 104?
Values for bytes 1, 2 and 3 are correct outside of loop.

Comment: If `BYTE` is a type, then what is this `BYTE (byte[block_size]);` !?

Comment: Sorry I was too fast. fread(&byte, sizeof(BYTE), block_size, inptr) solved it. BYTE (byte[block_size]) was written by mistake. Correct is without ().

Comment: Sorry I was too fast. fread(&byte, sizeof(BYTE), block_size, inptr) solved it. BYTE (byte[block_size]) was written by mistake. Correct is without ().

Comment: Actually, the main bug is this line: (remember it is in a loop reading one byte at a time.) 
        fread(&byte, sizeof(BYTE), 1, inptr);  This line should be: 
        fread(&byte[i], sizeof(BYTE), 1, inptr);

Comment: BTW: using defined names, where your code is only changing the capitalization is a VERY bad practice.  Something like BYTE myArray[block_size] would be much better.  And having all #define'd values be all caps would be better yet, for readability

Answer (score 2):

When you read in your byte array, you use the first value `byte[0]` or `*byte` as scratch space. There are several ways to fix this:

**Temporary variable** - Instead of using `*byte`, create a temporary variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < block_size; i++) {
    BYTE tmp;

    fread(&tmp, sizeof(BYTE), 1, inptr);
    byte[i] = tmp;
}
```

**Direct access** - You don't really need the temporary variable if you are just copying it later, so you can address the byte you want to write to directly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < block_size; i++) {
    fread(&byte[i], sizeof(BYTE), 1, inptr);
}
```

**Read blocks** - In fact, you don't even need the loop, because `fread` already reads a certain number of blocks:

```
fread(byte, sizeof(BYTE), block_size, inptr);
```

Your code looks a bit as if it mixed up the first two and the third method.

Finally, a note: `BYTE` is not a standard type, so please include the `typedef` so we know what you are talking about. I was thrown off track by your declaration

```
BYTE (byte[block_size]);
```

The parentheses look weird, although they seem to be correct syntax. Get rid of them and that line looks like an array declaration, which it is, of course:

```
BYTE byte[block_size];
```

Comment: Thank you! fread(&byte[i], sizeof(BYTE), 1, inptr) solve the problem.